# why the date value are stored as null in springboot using postman

Tags: mysql, reactjs, json, spring-boot

I was using Springboot and Mysql for my demoproject when I set `LocalDate` datatype and giving inputs through react the values are stored as null.

controller

[image]

output

[image]

entity

[image]

I tried using `@nonnull` annotation but it was of zero help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default when converting your json to object attributes, the attribute with the same name are paired together.
In your case you are getting null because of some capital cases (java is case sensitive).
In you json you have : `PeDate` and `CrDate` while in your object you have `peDate` and `crDate`.

Correct the json attributes by putting `peDate` instead of `PeDate` and `crDate` instead of `CrDate`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My issue was solved by your suggestion.

Comment: You should mark the response as correct, so that more people with the same problem can refer to it.